# Pairwise marginal effects at specific quintiles STATA-like in R's marginaleffects

Tags: r, marginal-effect

I would like to estimate marginal effects of two different variables.
In STATA, I have a two-way fixed effects model of type:

```
xtset region year
reg y x1 x2 c.x1#c.x2 x3 x4 i.region i.year [aw=pop], robust
```

In turn, I create the margins based on a specific set of quintiles from the variables, obtaining a 25-rows matrix of pairwise estimates.

```
margins, at(x1 =(0.02033865 0.0737 0.25173 1.04338 40.41884) x2 =(0.69 1.60 2.39 3.36 6.91))
```

What would be the correct translation of this code into R, using the `marginaleffects`  package?

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IeRUBF6EHGhhwodqlUtOhe5oVF0InzFI/view?usp=share_link) is the output of the STATA prediction applied to my dataset.

Below, instead, I created a reproducible example in both STATA and R, in order to make testing easier.

**STATA:**

```
set more off

cd "/your/dir"
use "https://dss.princeton.edu/training/Panel101.dta"

* Run regression with the interaction
xtset country year

reg y x1 x2 c.x1#c.x2 x3 i.country i.year, robust

centile x1 , centile(5 25 50 75 95)
centile x2 , centile(5 25 50 75 95)

* Create the margins based on distribution above
margins, at(x1 =(-.16 .32 .64 1.1 1.4) x2 =(-1.54 -1.22 -.46 1.61 1.80)) saving(predictions_test, replace)
```

Same code for R, where I am not sure the marginaleffects function is called correctly in order to replicate STATA's:

**R:**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sandwich)
library(lmtest)
library(plm)
library(multiwayvcov)
library(margins)
library(MASS)
library(marginaleffects)
library(data.table)
library(MASS)
library(jtools) # for clustered SE
library(dplyr)

setwd('/your/dir/')

# Load Data -----------------------------------------------------------


library(foreign)
library(plm)

data = data.table(read.dta("http://dss.princeton.edu/training/Panel101.dta"))

setkeyv(data,
        c("country", "year")
)

m = "x1 + x2 + I(x1 * x2) + x3 + factor(country) + factor(year)"
f = as.formula(paste("y ~", m, collapse=" + "))
ols = lm(f,
         # weights = pop,
         data = data 
)

x1quants = c(-.16, .32, .64, 1.1, 1.4) 
x2quants = c(-1.54, -1.22, -.46, 1.61, 1.80)

pred = predictions(ols, 
            by = c("x1", "x2"),
            variables = c("x1", "x2"),
            newdata=datagridcf(x1=x1quants, x2=x2quants),
            # cross=T
)

write.csv(pred, file='prediction_tests_R.csv', row.names = F)
```

Comment: Can you include the stata output?  I'm not familliar with stata and would like to make sure I can give you what you're looking for

Comment: Yes, `Stata` output would be very useful. In the meantime, you can also read this page, where I do side-by-side comparisons between `marginaleffects` and `Stata`: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/alternative_software.html#stata

Comment: You don't need the `variables` argument in the `predictions()` call. I can't replicate your results because I don't have access to `Stata` and because your two models don't match (no weights in `R` model). Have you read the link above and been able to exactly replicate the Stata examples? In particular, these: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/alternative_software.html#average-counterfactual-adjusted-predictions

Comment: Thanks a lot @Vincent . I had misunderstood the role of "variables" in together with "by" argument for predictions. Now the estimates are much more similar to STATA's one, although still computationally more expensive. Thanks for the tip (and the great package!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Vincent 's suggestion, the correct translation for the pairwise STATA behavior would be:

```
pred = predictions(ols, 
            by = c("x1", "x2"),
            newdata=datagridcf(x1=x1quants, x2=x2quants),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

From your description of the output, I'm lead to believe the right approach is

```
library(tidyverse)
library(marginaleffects)

x1 <- rnorm(1000, 2, 1)
x2 <- rnorm(1000, -2, 1)
y <- 2*x1 - x2 + 0.5*x1*x2 + rnorm(1000)

d <- tibble(x1, x2, y)

fit <- lm(y~x1*x2, data=d)

comparisons(
  fit, 
  variables = c('x1', 'x2'),
  newdata = datagrid(x1=quantile(x1), x2=quantile(x2)),
  cross = T
)
```

Here, I have specified that the marginal effects should be computed at the quantile of each variable (you're free to specify your own values).  This returns 25 marginal effects estimated at each combination of the variables specified in `newdata = datagrid(x1=quantile(x1), x2=quantile(x2))`.

If you edit your question to include stata output and a reproducible example in R, then I can verify this is the right appraoch.

Comment: I think that in `Stata`, `margins` will nearly always return an average estimate, so the equivalent would be `avg_comparisons()`. Also, the `at` argument in `Stata` builds what `marginaleffects` calls "counterfactual" dataset, by replicating the full observed data for each combination of values in `at`. So I think the analogous call in `marginaleffects` would use the `datagridcf()` function (note the "cf").

Comment: Demetri and @Vincent ,  thanks a lot for the feedback. I have updated the question with both the STATA output and a reproducible example for testing, I am not sure the call is correct. It doesn't matter now to programmatically include the computation of the quantiles, could be other user-generated inputs, I mostly wanna make sure the translation between STATA and R is correct.

Comment: @Vincent side note: I have tried `avg_comparisons` in `marginaleffects` with `datagridcf()` on a 8GB ram laptop with a dataset of roughly 4500 observations. It seems to saturate the RAM, and very slow computation. Seems to be very computationally inefficient with respect to `margins, at()` counterpart in STATA, which takes only a few seconds?